# Trying to figure out proper form of "that" in sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, diagramming

I currently have the sentence "Seahorses are the only fish that practice steadfast monogamy." to tree diagram for class, and cannot freakin' figure out what the word "that" would be used as in this sentence. Please help! Thanks. If you could also throw out a diagram of the sentence that'd be great.

Comment: "...what the word that would be used as in this sentence." What does this mean?

Comment: "That" has many different uses in English, I wasn't sure what it would qualify as in the sentence. Is it a determiner, relative pronoun, adverb, etc? I apologize for wording this awkwardly.

Comment: oh I see. I'd suggest putting some quotes around "that" in the question in that case, otherwise it's a bit of a garden-path sentence.

Comment: I think you mean "sentence diagram", I'm not sure what a "tree diagram" would be.

Comment: This is the diagram I did for this sentence http://imgur.com/AygMhUe

Comment: Your tree diagram already has the "that" properly identified as a relative word. So it seems you already know the answer to your question. :)

Comment: "Seahorses are [the [only **fish** (i) [that(i) __(i) practice steadfast monogamy]]]." -- Depending on your grammar, the word "that" is either a relative pronoun whose antecedent is the nominal "only fish", or it is a marker of clausal subordination (and the gap after it has as its antecedent the nominal "only fish". (The head noun of the predicative complement is, of course, the noun "fish").

Comment: @user83577, I just looked at you tree-diagram and it looks good, except that your attachment point of "that" to the predicate node is incorrect.  The proper attachment point is to the head NP "fish".

Answer (score 1):

"That" would be the "conjunction" in the above-written sentence.

Comment: Like this http://imgur.com/FMmqZjt

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Chenmunka How does this not provide an answer? The question asked for the role that the word serves in the sentence, this says that it's a conjunction that joins the two clauses.